# Fibonacci sequence Pseudo-code Java

Tags: java, pseudocode

I'm trying to refresh my pseudo-code understanding and wanted to see what the correct way of writing out a Fibonacci number @ n would be.

Given the code:

```
public class FibAtN{
     public static void main(String args[]){
          int j = 0;
          int k = j;
          int l = 1;
          int n =; /*input*/

          for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
               j=k;
               k=l;
               l=j+k;
          }
          System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Would the correct use of Pseudo-code be?

```
PROGRAM FibonnacciAtN
     INITIALIZE four integers (say: j,k,l,n)
     SET j equal zero, k equal j, l equal 1
     SET n equal to INPUT
     FOR (integer count is less than n, INCREMENT count every loop) DO
          SET j=k, k=l, l=j+k
     PRINT integer j
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pseudocode is not real code, you seem to assign some form of formality to pseudocode that doesn't exist. If it where so formal, you could just compile it and you wouldn't need to actual program in a different language. So if it describes he algorithm correctly, you should be good.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I was always somewhat under the impression that pseudocode had some sort of formal syntax or usage.  Good point though, thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: I'm sure there are teachers which expect a certain formality (and I'm also pretty sure that they won't have the same expectations), but in general pseudocode is just a loose method of describing an algorithm (more formal than just prose). Level of detail and 'exactness' will probably also depend on the reason for the pseudo-code. If it where more formal, then you'd probably be better off just programming the code directly.